# Attachment non-english name in BizTalk 2010 SMTP Adapter

Tags: biztalk

I'm using BizTalk 2010 SMTP Adapter for sending mail with attachments by setting them via property SMTP.Attachments

//Attachment

msgEmail(SMTP.Attachments)= AttachmentList;

I have files in several languages (In English and in Russian partialy) for example

My attachment list looks like this:

"C:\Temp\Files\EnglishNameFile.xml | C:\Temp\Files\RussianFileName_РусскоеИмя.xml";

After the sending Mail with this attachments the second file (it's name partialy in Russian) received without this part name

(The non-english part of name is DISAPPEARS)

like this:

RussianFileName_.xml ( must be RussianFileName_РусскоеИмя.xml)

The NON-English part is DISAPPEARS!!!

And if i have file that doesn't have latin latters (non-english) at all  than BizTalk SMTP Adapter change name

to default one like ATT41233.xml

I found this behaviour occur in other non-english languages also!!!

Unfortunately i'm not found any info about this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously that wrong character encodings are being used. The only property I can find on the [SMTP Adapter Property Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560686.aspx) is `EmailBodyTextCharset`, set it to `"utf-8"`.

Also you must use a `MIME/SMIME encoder` component in the pipeline of the send port (at the encoding stage).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work.
Thanks again :)

Comment: @LeonidUtyosov the cause might not be the biztalk SMTP adapter at all, but the mail client you are using. It could also happen on the mail server. You could use [smpt4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) to find out. With this simple mail server application you can see what the e-mails look like exactly as they are received. It's fairly easy to set up, let BTS send mails to localhost and smtp4dev will pick them up.